# IE8 addEventListener on change event not working on first click

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a site which has three radio inputs and based on which input is selected parts of the html page around it will change. Everything works perfect except in IE8(of course). My issue for this page is that when I click on the input which has an event listener of 'change' on it, nothing will happen, it is only until it is clicked the second time that the event will fire. I know that IE8 doesnt handle addEventListeners but I am using a pollyfill for all this and am using addEventListeners for tons of other things on the site and they work fine.

The second thing to note is that everything works fine in IE8 if I switch the event listener to a 'click' event. The only issue and reason why im not just switching it to 'click' is because of tabbing. I still what the user to still be able to tab through the form for a proper UX.

Lastly when I bring the site up in my VB for IE8, this functionality(even with the 'click' event) will not work until I put it in debugging mode and it finds all the polyfill.min.js errors. Then I can stop debugging and everything will then work as intended. I will provide a picture of my errors. I have no idea why and what is causing them. My guess would be some external script I am pull for third party functionality maybe. Cant figure that out yet.

[image: IE* polifill erros]

here is how the function is being called,

Here is where the function is called:

```
function attachToggleReportType (elem) {
    console.log('Trigger attachToggleReportType');
    elem.addEventListener('change', toggleReportType, false);
}
```

And here is the main function for the actions to happen based on the event

```
function toggleReportType () {
    console.log('Trigger toggleReportType');
    var reportOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.report'),
        reportIncToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');
        console.log(this.getAttribute('data-sample-report-link'));
    reportSample({
        href: this.getAttribute('data-sample-report-link'),
        src: this.getAttribute('data-sample-report-image'),
        title: this.getAttribute('data-sample-report-title')
    });

    reportIncToggle.forEach(toggleInclude);
}
```

Comment: Using an unminified version of polyfill.js and looking at the stack traces on the errors might help.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution for my problem. It is not perfect but it worked fine for me, for now. It was a pretty odd issue because in IE8 my event listener with a type of 'change' would always have a click delay on it. So no matter which radio I would click, the only time the event would fire is when I clicked again anywhere on the screen the second time. I know IE8 doesnt handle addEventListeners but I was using a polyfill for accommodate this. I also would get a polyfill error when in debug mode, so I wonder if this is an issue related to that. Anyways, i resolved this issue for now by including a 'change' event  listen for modern browsers, then in  IE8 i switched it to an on 'focus' event and everything works perfectly still. I hate the idea of having two event types but it was the only way to resolve this bug. Also to note, the change event still worked in IE8 on the second click, so trying to detect if the browser could handle this event type wasn't an option for me.